# How to add onclientclick attribute to a Linkbutton from C#code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton, onclientclick

I am trying to add onclientclick attribute to a linkbutton that has been created in the C# code only which gives error.
Following is the code for the same :

```
LinkButton imghelp = new LinkButton();
imghelp.ID = "btnhelp";
imghelp.Text = "<i class = 'fa fa-question-circle-o'></i>";
imghelp.onClientClick = "javascript:ShowHelp(\"" + Languagecode + "\",\"" + context + "\",\"" + subcontext + "\")";
```

The error is : "**System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton does not contain a definition for onClientClick**"

Comment: The docs show that it is [OnClientClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx), have you tried capitalizing the `On`?

Comment: Exactly what the problem was. I don't know how I missed on that. Thanks a lot @MattClark

Comment: No worries, happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

you should have to use `imghelp.Attributes.Add("onClientClick", "Your function here");` because if you directly add event like you have done in your code it will always throws an error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nitin Kumar . But the main problem was because I didnt capitalise the 'O' of OnClientClick. Directly adding event worked for link button but not for label. So for label I did as your answer suggested.

Answer (score 2):

```
imghelp.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ShowHelp(your parameter)");
```

your javascript function

```
 function ShowHelp(your parameter)
 {
       // your code
 }
```